Node.JS Redirecting has no effect, and no errors
I'm making an application with Node.JS and while I was trying to redirect a user from the login page to another page, nothing was happening.
I used this login function where I use res.redirect(307, "/home/userPAGE") to redirect the user:
const login = asyncHandler (async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    if (!email || !password){
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Email or password not provided");
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({email});
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({
            user: {
                username: user.id,
                email: user.email,
                id: user.id
            },
        }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {expiresIn: "30m"});
        console.log("Logged in!");
        res.redirect(307, "/home/userPAGE");
    }
    else {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Email or Password is not valid");
    }

});

Then, this path should loat my userpage.html file:
app.use("/home/userPAGE", (req, res) => {
    console.log("HERE")
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./public/userpage.html"));
});

but it doesn't. If I look at the logs I see HERE, but nothing happens after.
I've looked through other's posts, but it looks like I have similar code to people in the solutions, so I'm confused to what the problem is.
This was one of the answers:
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/arena.html"));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.get('/arena', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/arena.html");
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  console.log("User name = " + username);

  // Note how I'm redirecting the user to the /arena URL.
  // When you issue a redirect, you MUST redirect the user
  // to a webpage on your site. You can't redirect them to
  // a file you have on your disk.
  res.redirect("/arena");
});

app.listen(3000);


You have app.use, since you're defining a route it needs to be app.get("/home/userPAGE", (req, res) => {...

I tried to replace app.use with app.get, but then I dont't even get to see the log message.

What happens if you try to go directly to that path in your browser instead of redirecting to it? Also where is the file that you're defining the /home/userPAGE route, is it possible the way it's being included in your app.js it's getting prefixed with something?

The path works if I go directly in the browser, the /home/userPAGE route is defined in my main, index.js, file, and what do you mean by prefixed

If you're using a routes folder with express and including a file like this: app.use('/api/admin', adminApiRouter);, any get or post routes defined in that file would be prefixed with /api/admin/

I am using a routes folder, but don't have an admin file. It only includes routes branching from my index.js routes.
